# How to disable print option for PDF in iframe

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, printing

I'm showing a PDF in an `<iframe>` as follows:

```
<iframe src="/itextPdfServlet" height="600px" width="700px"></iframe>
```

I would like to disable the print option for this. How can I achieve this?

my servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fullPath = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("fullPath");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        ServletOutputStream out = null;
        try{
            File file = new File( fullPath );
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream( file );
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileIn);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("fullPath"));
            stamper.setEncryption("reader_password".getBytes(), "permission_password".getBytes(),  
                    ~(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING ), PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
            stamper.close();
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
            document.newPage();
            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0); 
            document.add(new Paragraph("my timestamp"));
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            document.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating visitors or customers like enemies might not be in your best interest. You can disable printing in the options of a PDF file when generating the file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("testpdf.pdf");

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("my-pdf-file.pdf"));

stamper.setEncryption("reader_password".getBytes(), "permission_password".getBytes(),   ~(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING ), PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);

stamper.close();
```

But I know at least one PDF viewer which doesn't care about these options. I know a lot of tools that can make screenshots, so even if your PDF makes me angry, I just print the screenshot. There are screen automation tools that will even page through the file for me, make a screenshot for every page and a little script will compile a new PDF from that.

You can also try to disable printing with JavaScript in the web browser. That would then force me to install a tool like Tampermonkey or similar that kicks your script out of my browser.

Usually, a much better approach is to put watermarks in the PDF file which say who downloaded / bought the file and then harass them, if the PDF file leaks out. That way, you're not annoying *everyone*.

That said, consider how much your PDFs are worth and how much suing someone would cost (money and negative feedback wise). Most of the time, investing your money in great service will earn you much more money than you can lose by people printing PDFs (they would also have to do something with those prints before it could have any impact on your revenue, rights, ...)

Comment: The reasonwhy i want to disable print option is it has confidential pdf that must be viewed by client and they can view it but they should not be able to print

Comment: I did this aaron but still it shows print and download option in iframe

Comment: That's my point: Since many people abused this feature, browsers and PDF viewers have options to ignore requests by a PDF document / javascript to turn off printing or the context menu. If your PDF is confidential, print it and send it by courier, have the courier stand by while the client reads it and have it brought back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with iText, but I assume this might help you a little:
[iText Java disable print pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059434/itext-java-disable-print-pdf)